# Scala inconclusive Assertion

Tags: scala, scalatest

I am writing an integration test in Scala. The test starts by searching for a configuration file to get access information of another system.

If it finds the file then the test should run as usual, however if it does not find the file I don't want to fail the test, I would rather make it inconclusive to indicate that the test can not run because of missing configurations only.

In C# I know there is [Assert.Inconclusive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243815(v=vs.120).aspx) which is exactly what I want, is there anything similar in Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need here is `assume` / `cancel` (from "Assumptions" section, found [here](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.2.4/index.html#org.scalatest.Assertions)):

> Trait Assertions also provides methods that allow you to cancel a test. You would cancel a test if a resource required by the test was unavailable. For example, if a test requires an external database to be online, and it isn't, the test could be canceled to indicate it was unable to run because of the missing database.